# Firebase Email Link Authentication in Android, Link not displaying in gmail

Tags: android, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I have configured the dependencies for email link authentication, added the SHA keys, also enabled the email verification, App check is enabled, support email is configured.

[image: Reference]

Dynamic link is there as shown below :

[image: Reference]

Intent filter for Login Activity in Manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:host="techlearnitnotes.page.link" android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="techlearnitnotes.page.link" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Code LoginActivity.java:

```
    package com.techlearnit.notes;
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;
    import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.techlearnit.notes.NotificationRecyclerView.NotificationActivity;
    import com.techlearnit.notes.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding;
    
    import java.util.Objects;
    
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private ActivityLoginBinding binding;
        Animation btgone, btgtwo;
        SharedPreferences shp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor shpEditor;
        String nameFromDB, emailFromDB, newAccount;
        ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings;
        private String email_address, email_link, pending_email;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
            FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
            firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
    
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    
            shp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            pending_email = shp.getString("key_pending_email", null);
            newAccount = shp.getString("newaccount", "");
            if (pending_email != null)
                Objects.requireNonNull(binding.emailinputlayout.getEditText()).setText(pending_email);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
                email_link = intent.getData().toString();
                if (mAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(email_link)) {
                    binding.topanimation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.animationpurposebuttonslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.animationpurposeloginbuttonlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.confirmationlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    binding.emailtview.setText("Your email " + pending_email + " has been verified sucessfully");
                    authenticateUser(pending_email, newAccount);
                }
            }
    
            btgone = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btgone);
            btgtwo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btgtwo);
            binding.animationpurposebuttonslayout.startAnimation(btgone);
            binding.animationpurposeloginbuttonlayout.startAnimation(btgtwo);
    
            binding.btnVerify.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (!validateEmail())
                    return;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isUser();
            });
        }
    
        private void isUser() {
            email_address = Objects.requireNonNull(binding.emailinputlayout.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email_address);
            checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        newAccount = "no";
                        nameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(email_address).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        emailFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(email_address).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    } else {
                        newAccount = "yes";
                    }
                    shpEditor = shp.edit();
                    shpEditor.putString("key_pending_email", email_address);
                    shpEditor.putString("newaccount", newAccount);
                    shpEditor.apply();
                    actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                            .setUrl("https://notes-2dc3c.firebaseapp.com/")
                            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                            .setAndroidPackageName("com.techlearnit.notes", false, null)
                            .build();
                    mAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email_address, actionCodeSettings)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An email has been sent to your email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
    
        private Boolean validateEmail() {
            String val = Objects.requireNonNull(binding.emailinputlayout.getEditText()).getText().toString();
            if (val.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email Field cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                binding.emailinputlayout.requestFocus();
                return false;
            } else
                return true;
        }
    
        public void authenticateUser(String emailaddress, String newAccount) {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailLink(emailaddress, email_link)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        pending_email = null;
                        shpEditor.remove("key_pending_email");
                        shpEditor.commit();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) { // Success
} else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error signing in with email link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Email is being sent from firebase but without any link :

[image: Reference]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Dynamic Link domain for actionCodeSettings parameter:

```
 ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                                .setAndroidPackageName(
                                        /* yourPackageName= */ "...",
                                        /* installIfNotAvailable= */ true,
                                        /* minimumVersion= */ null)
                                .setHandleCodeInApp(true) // This must be set to true
                                .setUrl("an authorized domain found in FB console")
                                .setDynamicLinkDomain("dynamic link domain found in FB console")
                            .build();
```